# often + used to

Tags: adverbs, word-order

I know that adverbs of frequency such as "often" are usually put before the main verb (or after if the main verb is "to be") or at the end of the sentence. Examples:

- I often walk on the beach / I walk on the beach often.
- I will often run on the beach / I will run on the beach often.
- I am often angry with my students. / I am angry with my students often.

However, I am not sure which verb is considered the main one in  sentences with "used to" and therefore I am not sure of the position of "often" in sentences with it. Which one of the sentences below is more usual?

- I used to often go skiing in the winter.
- I often used to go skiing in the winter.

Answer (score 1):

You would put "often" at the end of the sentence, like you did in your example.
"I used to go skiing in the winter often."

Or perhaps even better would be:
"I used to go skiing often in the winter."

Comment: Can you provide reasons (backed up by authoritative sources) as to why "often" in that particular sentence should be placed at the end? Also, can you please explain why *" ... skiing often in the winter"* is better than the other 3 options? You can edit your answer to include those points, that would make the answer great!