Position of adverbs before main verbs or between auxiliaries?
What are the possible positions of adverbs of frequency, opinion completeness and others when used in sentences containing auxiliaries and modals? I know they go mid-position but can that be in front of the main verb or between the modal and auxiliaries or in front of auxiliaries? Cambridge books usually emphasize one position, and I have always wondered if that's the only correct possibility. Could I get some thorough explanation, please? Many thanks in advance.

Your question is too broad. Be more specific please and/or provide examples. Otherwise, we have to do all the work.

Often I eat meat. I often eat meat. I eat meat often. They're all fine, and mean much the same. But I eat often meat isn't so good, whatever it might mean. Note that often is an adverb of frequency. Things are very different with Only I eat meat. I only eat meat. I eat only meat. I eat meat only, which are all perfectly valid - again, with only two clearly distinct senses.

There are a lot of similar questions so you should search this site and try and narrow your question down to something more specific. For example, here's 3 about the position of often: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/318019/often-not-used-for-habits https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230535/often-used-to https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230661/this-often-happened-vs-this-happened-often There are many others on other adverbs.

As there’re no examples from the OP, we look at two cases with auxiliaries and modals.
Ngram
Ngram
Having such adverbs placed between the modal verb and the auxiliary verb seems to be the most common.
The results also show that the other two positions are possible too.  Some adverbs in certain context can have more than one possible position among modal, auxiliary, and lexical verbs.
The frequency of each type of adverb positioning depends on what we want to focus on.
This site says

With two helping verbs, place the adverb in one of two positions.

If the adverb modifies the entire thought expressed by the sentence, place it after the first helping verb:
They will certainly have read your submission by Thursday.
If the adverb is strongly modifying the main verb, place it directly in front of the main verb:
The boy’s behavior has been repeatedly reprimanded.


